# Angular.js Partials

Tags: html, css, web, angularjs

I'm making a really simple website and was curious how I can modularize the content sections of the body while leaving the static portions of the site alone. I figured using partials would be the key but they operate much differently than I had originally thought. This is my first time using Angular so I'm not very familiar with anything just yet.

Right now the site has a simple design similar to the following:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href={{option.path}}>Option 1</a></li>
      <li><a href={{option.path}}>Option 2</a></li>
      <li><a href={{option.path}}>Option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>   <------ content changes with selected option in .sidebar
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Barring the inherent syntax errors here, what can I do so that when I click on an option in `.sidebar` such that the `{{option.path}}` won't just be appended to the URL?

Currently, this is what I have happening:

1. I have my site open on index.html where the .content section is completely empty.
2. The user then chooses an option and I want to direct their browser from /index.html to /partials/option1.html.
3. If the user then click AGAIN on option 1, their browser directs to /partials/partials/option1.html, which returns a 404 error.

Is there a way to avoid the problem in part 3 or is that simply how partials are meant to work?

Comment: It appears that you are trying to implement routes.  Check out this [Egghead.io](http://www.egghead.io/video/nZrbZ_sYShU) tutorial video, (and the rest of them).  It should get you in the right direction.

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular JS uses [$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route) to designate partial templates to URL's. You will also need to learn about [ngView](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angView) to make this work.

I admit egghead.io is a great resource for Angular but I think you are in need of this specific screen-cast => http://youtu.be/i9MHigUZKEM

[This LinkedIn group also contains every Angular.js resource I have come across.](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?home=&gid=4896676)